# Filling a div with circles. CSS or SVG?

Tags: html, css, svg

I'm currently developing a website where i want the opening div (which will fill the screen) to be filled with circles that i can control and animate through CSS. My first approach was to create them in HTML like below but this ended up looking like a lot of code. I then thought of creating an svg in illustrator and targeting the different paths. However, the SVG was 1mb in size. I'm just wondering what you guys think the best way of doing this is whilst making it as minimal as possible?

I'm 100% sure you can do something like this in Javascript but i have zero knowledge in the language.

```
<div class="circles" >
  <div class="circle-cluster"  data-center="transform:translate(0px, 0px)" data-bottom-top="transform:translate(0px, 500px)">
    <div class="circle" ></div>
    <div class="circle"></div>
    <div class="circle"></div>
  </div>
  <div class="circle-cluster" data-center="transform:translate(0px, 0px) rotate(-90deg)" data-bottom-top="transform:translate(0px, 200px) rotate(-90deg)" >
    <div class="circle"></div>
    <div class="circle"></div>
    <div class="circle"></div>
  </div>
  <div class="circle-cluster" data-center="transform:translate(0px, 0px) rotate(-90deg)" data-bottom-top="transform:translate(0px, 300px)rotate(-90deg)">
    <div class="circle"></div>
    <div class="circle"></div>
    <div class="circle"></div>
  </div>
  <div class="circle-cluster" data-center="transform:translate(0px, 0px);rotate(180deg)" data-bottom-top="transform:translate(0px, -200px);rotate(180deg)">
    <div class="circle"></div>
    <div class="circle"></div>
    <div class="circle"></div>
  </div>
  <div class="circle-cluster" data-center="transform:translate(0px, 0px)" data-bottom-top="transform:translate(0px, 50px)">
    <div class="circle"></div>
    <div class="circle"></div>
    <div class="circle"></div>
  </div>
  <div class="circle-cluster" data-center="transform:translate(0px, 0px)rotate(180deg)" data-bottom-top="transform:translate(0px, 450px)rotate(180deg)">
    <div class="circle"></div>
    <div class="circle"></div>
    <div class="circle"></div>
  </div>
  <div class="circle-cluster" data-center="transform:translate(0px, 0px)rotate(180deg)" data-bottom-top="transform:translate(0px, 450px)rotate(180deg)">
    <div class="circle"></div>
    <div class="circle"></div>
    <div class="circle"></div>
  </div>
  <div class="circle-cluster" data-center="transform:translate(0px, 0px)rotate(180deg)" data-bottom-top="transform:translate(0px, -300px)rotate(180deg)">
    <div class="circle"></div>
  </div>
  <div class="circle-cluster" data-center="transform:translate(0px, 0px);rotate(180deg)" data-bottom-top="transform:translate(0px, 350px);rotate(180deg)">
    <div class="circle"></div>
    <div class="circle"></div>
  </div>
  <div class="circle-cluster" data-center="transform:translate(0px, 0px)rotate(180deg)" data-bottom-top="transform:translate(0px, 300px)rotate(180deg)">
    <div class="circle"></div>
    <div class="circle"></div>
    <div class="circle"></div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Constructive! (Y)

Comment: Could you post a picture of desired result also if you want to use js you should tag your question with js or jquery.

Comment: We're not here to create solutions from scratch for you. You need to do prior research and in your case that means learning javascript.

Comment: I wasn't coming here to get a solution. I said i don't know Javascript in my question and i'm not bothered about using it. What i wanted to know is if using CSS is better than using an SVG? What is better for perfomance? Is using a 1mb SVG smaller than writing lines of HTML?

Comment: Recommendations questions (i.e. what's the best X to do Y) are off-topic here.

Comment: Apologies. I think i'll go for the SVG option anyways.